Hypoteneous not showing up in C
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {

    double P;
    double B;

    printf("\nPerpendicular:");
    scanf("%lf", P);
    printf("\n Base:");
    scanf("%lf", B);
    double H = sqrt(P * P + B * B);
    printf("Hypoteneous:%lf", H);

    return 0;
} 

I am trying to make a program which allows the user to find the hypoteneous of a triangle by inputing the base and perpendicular from the user but when i try to run the program it only lets me input Base and perpendicular and than just closes without showing the hypoteneous

In scanf, you're not passing the address of P and B. You need to do: scanf("%lf", &P). Fixing that will do what you want.

The root of your problem is that you most likely haven't enabled warnings when you invoke the compiler. With gcc and -Wall you will get the warning format ‘%lf’ expects argument of type ‘double *’, but argument 2 has type ‘double’ after including stdio.h. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/57842757/337149.

Also add a newline to your last print.

You just needed to make sure that you pass the reference of the variables you want to read in:
    printf("\nPerpendicular:");
    scanf("%lf", &P);
    printf("\n Base:");
    scanf("%lf", &B);

